# API Platform - Invalid value provided (invalid IRI?). How to POST with relations?

Tags: api-platform.com

I setup a pretty straightforward `Group -> GroupUser -> User` relationship (GroupUser being a join table with additional data fields, Group OneToMany GroupUsers, which has ManyToOne Group and User, and User with OneToMany GroupUser) and fail to POST to the API, receiving an `invalid IRI` error. There seems to be quite some confusion about this, I found several posts ([here](https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/252) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50586153/api-platform-invalid-value-provided-invalid-iri)) on this but none clearly addresses my most basic scenario (I followed the API platform documentation and have a Symfony4 with a require `api-platform/api-pack` installation).

I am using IRI to associate the objects, but the following POST does not work (I do have a user with id 1 and a group with id 1) and returns the `Invalid value provided (invalid IRI?)` error:

```
curl -X POST "http://api.platform.local/group_users" -H "accept: application/ld+json" -H "Content-Type: application/ld+json" -d "{ \"group\": \"/groups/1\", \"user\": \"/users/1\", \"role\": \"member\"}"
```

Here are my entities:

App/Entity/Group

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="GroupUser", mappedBy="group")      
 */
private $users;
```

App/Entity/User

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="GroupUser", mappedBy="user")
 */
private $groups;
```

App/Entity/GroupUser

```
/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(
 *     nullable=false,
 *     onDelete="CASCADE"
 * )
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(
 *    inversedBy="users",
 *    targetEntity="App\Entity\Group"
 * )
 */
private $group;

/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(
 *     nullable=false,
 *     onDelete="CASCADE"
 * )
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(
 *     inversedBy="groups",
 *     targetEntity="App\Entity\User"
 * )
 */
private $user;
```

I must be missing something fundamental, but the documentation doesn't seem to require anything else. This post didn't help, I even added an id to the UserGroup entity just for that, initially I only had `user` and `group` as table ids.

Your help is appreciated, many thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured this out, actually I made two mistakes:

1. I passed values to __construct to populate a GroupUser upon construction. I removed the __construct entirely, this didn't play nice with the API Platform and the automatic IRI creation.
2. I used a composite primary key on group_id and user_id for my GroupUser table, which I abandoned in favour of an own ID.

Pretty straight forward, here's what I added to the GroupUser entity:

```
  /**
   * @var int
   *
   * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
   * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
   * @ORM\Id
   */
  private $id;
```

And don't forget the getter method:

```
  public function getId(): ?int
  {
    return $this->id;
  }
```